# Automatic setting of Local Time zone w/DST

Tags: windows-server-2003

I can derive latitude and longitude and UTC time from GPS NMEA sentences.
Now, how can I automaticly adjust the Windows local time zone on my PC (2003 Server OS), based on this?
Also, Is there an easy way of distributing this to clients based on code or apps software?
Preferred programming environment is .NET, C# & Visual Studio.

I use a GPS Time server (GPS clock with antenna) today, but this could not support other than UTC. I want to set computers in my TCP/UDP network to correct time zone w/DST based on coordinates derived from GPS, so manually setting of all is not required.

Comment: You can start with this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mark, but to me it seems that hook up to Internet is mandatory in the link given.
This isn't necessarily the case onboard a drill ship.
Therefore I want to extract it from the GPS data always available.
Parsing might be done based on a time zone table located on the onboard server (?)

This is the antenna I had in mind (hooked up to my server serial port):
http://www.trimble.com/timing/acutime-gold-gps-antenna.aspx?dtID=overview