# How to get local time based on GPS coordinates?

Tags: php, timezone, geolocation

My script has as input the latitude and longitude values as GPS coordinates.

How can I get the current local time?

**Are out there solutions that do not use databases or web services?**

PHP has a method to [retrieve location based on a timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getlocation.php), I am wondering if the reverse exists or not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude)

Comment: That dup is 2 years old, I hope PHP 5.3 has some inbuilt method for this one.

Answer (score 2):

geonames.org provide a range of webservices that can be used to get details from latitude and longitude. For example http://ws.geonames.org/timezone?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&style=full

You can just fetch that with your PHP code and parse the result.

See http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html for details of the available webservices.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [datafile](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/releases/tzdata2014b.tar.gz). The data you are looking for is in zone.tab. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) also has an overview of it - the table is generated from the datafiles.