# Ruby gem for finding timezone of location

Tags: ruby, web-services, timezone, rubygems, location

I have a location (city, state), date, and time and I want to convert it to utc, but need to first find the timezone of the location. I've done a little research and everything seems to point to either earthtools or geonames but both webservices appear to be latitude and longitude only. Is there a service or gem or any other way to find the timezone based on this format of location? or how can the location be converted to latitude and longitude?

Comment: See also [this community wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can easily get a latitude and longitude using the [google maps geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding). There are ruby implementations for the API like [GeoKit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org). Once you have that you can use the [timezone gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/timezone) to easily get the timezone of a latitude and longitude. The gem makes it easy to do time conversions in your timezone as well.

Here is an example using [GeoKit](https://github.com/andre/geokit-gem) and [TimeZone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone).

```
require 'geokit'
require 'timezone'

res = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode('140 Market St, San Francisco, CA')
timezone = Timezone::Zone.new(:latlon => res.ll)

timezone.zone
=> "America/Los_Angeles"
timezone.time Time.now
=> 2011-12-01 14:02:13 UTC
```

Comment: Thank you this seems like the best option

Comment: If you have the latitude and longitude, you can use the [nearest_time_zone gem](https://github.com/buytruckload/nearest_time_zone) to find the name of the time zone without making any web service calls.

Comment: the above did not work. The correct answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578695/rails-get-timezone-from-latitude-and-longitude-using-timezone

Answer (score 9):

For the second part of the question, see the accepted answer to this question:

[Determine timezone from latitude/longitude without using web services like Geonames.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584602)

As stated in that answer, you should:

> - Download the database of cities from geonames.org
> - convert it to a compact lat/lon -> timezone list
> - use an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) implementation to efficiently lookup the nearest city (or rather, its
>     timezone) to a given coordinate

Keep in mind also that many U.S. states belong to a single time zone, which should make the job easier.

Comment: [nearest_time_zone](https://github.com/buytruckload/nearest_time_zone) does just that. I made it after reading this answer because I didn't want to have the performance penalty of calling a web service.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own calls to a geolocation service, like Google Maps to translate City, State into latitude and longitude.  There are also open database seeds that will give you latitude and longitudes for cities around the world.  You could make a location model and seed that table with one of those.

Here is one place you can download geolocation data for free: http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

Answer (score 1):

Check this gem: https://github.com/sck-v/google_timezone

It uses google timezone api to determine timezone by known latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0):

Check the Gist at https://gist.github.com/4676207 for a version that uses Google's API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/). Together with the [Geocoder gem](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) you can easily find all timezone ids :)