# Rails Get timezone from latitude and longitude using Timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

Iam working on a Rails app where I want to get **timezone** from latitude and longitude. I searched for this on stackoverflow and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349817/ruby-gem-for-finding-timezone-of-location) as the best way to do this.

I installed both the gems **geokit** and **timezone** and tried to implement the same in my console:

```
require 'geokit'
require 'timezone'
res = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode('140 Market St, San Francisco, CA')
timezone = Timezone::Zone.new(:latlon => res.ll)
```

But I get this *error*:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

I checked the documentation for [Timezone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone). 
They ask to get a username by signing up. But I have not received any activation mail yet. Can someone please suggest some solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this community wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the call Timezone::Zone.new(:latlon => res.ll) does not work (at least I got the same error). I think it is due to changes in format of res.ll value returned from Google. But this call should do the job:

`Timezone::Zone.new(lat: res.lat, lon: res.lng)`

**However**, first make sure that you create an account with GeoNames and **active** it [here](http://www.geonames.org/manageaccount). You also have to create and configure an initializer for timezone gem. The later is described over here: [timezone/lib/timezone/configure.rb](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone/blob/34c94ea5679bc6fdaf3ba464bce0a3ef2d76e42e/lib/timezone/configure.rb)