# get timezone from location name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

As we can get timezone from country code like

```
c = TZInfo::Country.get('US')
zones = c.zone_identifiers
```

this returns all zones of country.

But I need specific zone of location i.e. "washington, USA"
Is there a way to get timezone from location name?

so we can get timezone by giving location name("washington, USA")

Comment: You can find the answer here, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349817/ruby-gem-for-finding-timezone-of-location#

Comment: Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode require complete address but here rkp has only location .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download the [geonames db](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip) and compare lat/lng to the nearest place (with timezone) in the db

- Download the database of cities from [geonames.org](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip)
- convert it to a compact lat/lon -> timezone list