# Timezone Gem - certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, timezone

I want to use the Time zone gem to convert lat and long to a time zone;

1. I have added the gem in to my file
2. I have created `timezone.rb` in `config/initializers`
3. I enabled the Google Maps Time Zone API, and added a server key

timezone.rb file:

```
Timezone::Lookup.config(:google) do |c|
  c.api_key = 'server_key'
end
```

When I type to rails console;

```
> timezone = Timezone['America/Los_Angeles']
 => #<Timezone::Zone name: "America/Los_Angeles">
```

This works but when I try to use lat and long google gives connection error;

```
> timezone = Timezone.lookup(-34.92771808058, 138.477041423321)
Timezone::Error::Google: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check this [Github](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone), it will explain everything to you about [Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro) using ruby.

Just make sure you follow this steps:

1. Ensure you have a Google API Key, server key
2. Enable the Google Maps Time Zone API
3. Configure your lookup. NOTE: in Rails it is recommended that you add this code to an initializer

.

```
Timezone::Lookup.config(:google) do |c|
  c.api_key = 'your_google_api_key_goes_here'
  c.client_id = 'your_google_client_id' # if using 'Google for Work'
end
```

For more information, you can also check this [thread](http://apprentice.craic.com/tutorials/48) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349817/ruby-gem-for-finding-timezone-of-location).