# What TimeZone should i use in Laravel App and why?

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

Laravel provided the following timezone out of the box.

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

Am confused about the right Time Zone to use in my laravel application.
My application involves users world wide.

So I don't know if i should use the default Time Zone provided by Laravel or use my country Time Zone which i think is UTC+01:00 and what are the implications of using a wrong Time Zone in web application.

Comment: I don't see how this is specific to laravel.

Comment: I understand Time Zone is not laravel specific but I want to know if Laravel takes care of the time zone for me

Comment: If they say "We have gone ahead and set this to a sensible default for you", I'd consider leaving it as it is. You might find this StackOverflow question interesting: [*How can I handle time zones in my webapp?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10834665/1364007).

Comment: Opinion based question

Comment: Everything set to UTC and later on when your app grows tell carbon to convert xx date to whatever timezone you want (preferably whatever user sets in profile etcetera).

Answer (score 0):

You should set your app timezone regarding the users of the application. There no relations between Laravel and timezone.