# Resolve geographical/GPS coordinates to current local time

Tags: php, geolocation

I am trying to resolve a location's coordinates (latitude, longitude), to an accurate current local time.

For example, let's say I have a list of locations on a website. When I look at a specific location I will always know its latitude/longitude (it could be anywhere in the world). I would like to display the current time at that location.

I can write something from scratch by myself, but I was wondering if there are any libraries/plugins that would allow me to do this faster.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude)