# Android: Is there a way to get timezone for Country name?

Tags: android, timezone, maps

Is there a way to get the Timezone given the name of a Country? I use `getCountryName()` in Maps to get the name of the Country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems difficult considering that some countries span over multiple time zones.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the timezone of the place the user clicks on?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude

Comment: @benvd, might be worth posting as an answer if you want points for it ;-)

Comment: Thank you benvd. Can you please post it as an answer so that I can mark it? :) until then, I am going to mark this as the answer :D