# How to get country name from time of android mobile?

Tags: java, php, android

Hi I am very new to Android Development. I want to pick the country name based on the current time of the particular mobile, while clicking the button. How can i do it? Any body tell me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    String gmt1=TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID()).getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.SHORT);
    String gmt2=TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID()).getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.LONG);
    Log.d("Tag","TimeZone : "+gmt1+"\t"+gmt2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems difficult considering most timezones contain multiple countries (and countries multiple timezones as well).

See: [Android: Is there a way to get timezone for Country name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096014/android-is-there-a-way-to-get-timezone-for-country-name)

Answer (score 3):

Per above, the closest you'll get comes from [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/80427-how-to-get-time-zone/):

> For getting the time zone, check out the "O" and "T" format specifiers
>   of the date() function. "O" will give you the Difference to Greenwich
>   time (GMT) in hours (your time zone offset) and "T" will give you the
>   time zone abbreviation like "EST" for Eastern Standard Time.

e.g. `<?php echo date("T"); ?>` will give you the executing PHP script timezone, for the user timezome you can pass their date/time as the second argument.

Comment: You wont be able to extract a country from a time- as many countries lie across the same date/time lines geographically. The best you can do is get the timezone, and filter countries within that. You will need to provide PHP with the end users time (sent from their device for example), then you can use PHP's date function to interpret the timezone they are in

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats possible because you can have MANY MANY countries on the same time. For example, just take the GMT+/-0 time zone, you'll have England, France, Spain, Portugal, and a few others you can get from the african countries. You can't do it like that.

What i'd suggest is to implement a GEOIP location using for example: MaxMind GEOIP. You have some very powerful tools available in PEAR for that and it took me about 4 hours to setup the library, understand the code and do the code to query. I was querying for IPs and countries and even states/provinces in less than 4 hours. You can't get faster than that unless your a genious :)