# debian squeeze cannot use local timezones no matter what you do

Tags: date, timezone, debian

I need to use the CLI to see the time in arbitrary timezones. However, Debian doesn't respond to the recommended solution.

First, I set the local timezone.

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Then, I set the system time.

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

I update the hardware clock to reflect the system time.

```
hwclock --systohc --utc
```

Now, I follow this post:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/display-different-timezones-in-command-line-927660/

Which says that I can complete my task using a command such as this:
`TZ=UTC date && TZ=CDT date && TZ=IST date`

However, this is the output I get:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata && ntpdate pool.ntp.org && hwclock --systohc --utc && TZ=UTC date && TZ=CDT date && TZ=IST date

Current default time zone: 'America/Chicago'
Local time is now:      Tue Apr 16 14:45:29 CDT 2013.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Apr 16 19:45:29 UTC 2013.

16 Apr 19:45:38 ntpdate[12036]: adjust time server 199.102.46.73 offset -0.036668 sec
Tue Apr 16 19:45:39 UTC 2013
Tue Apr 16 19:45:39 CDT 2013
Tue Apr 16 19:45:39 IST 2013
```

Comment: In the future, please format code and session transcripts in your post so that the lines do not run together.

Answer (score 1):

`CDT` and `IST` aren't valid timezone names, so `date` is defaulting to show you `UTC` time if you attempt to use those as your timezone.

I'm not sure which timezones you actually meant to use, but try a couple of these. They are valid timezone names.

```
TZ=Asia/Shanghai date
TZ=America/Vancouver date
TZ=Europe/London date
```

Comment: How to convert from abbreviation (e.g., CDT) to something that date will accept (e.g., America/Chicago)? How to get the timezone for an arbitrary city? Say, for example, that I want the timezone for Ludhiana, India. That city is not listed under /usr/share/zoneinfo.

Comment: You cannot convert from short 3-letter timezone abberviations to Olson timezone names because the short abberviations are ambiguous. For example, `America/Montreal` and `Australia/Sydney` both make use of the `EST` abbreviation. As for getting the timezone of an arbitrary city or getting the timezone from a latitude and longitude, this has been asked and answered many times before on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669366/timezone-from-geolocation for just one example among many.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Those 3-letter abbreviations had me completely stumped.
I think this describes the steps required to automate this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city.
I ended up getting the specific information I needed from wikipedia: "In the tz database it is represented by Asia/Kolkata."
My final command is this:
`( TZ=America/Chicago date ; TZ=Asia/Kolkata date )`.
For more timezones, I would use this:
`for K in America/Chicago Asia/Kolkata ; do TZ=$K date ; done`