# How to translate timezone full names to tz abbreviations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails 3.x app I need to display time zone abbreviations (EST, PST, CST, etc.) rather than the full time zone name.  I've seen a number of discussions that seem to address the issue, but in overly verbose manners.

**Is there a gem or a very concise method to handle this that could be used to map them properly?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For the current time zone:

```
Time.zone.now.strftime('%Z')
```

Or for a list of time zones:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map do |zone|
  Time.now.in_time_zone(zone).strftime('%Z')
end
```

It works, but it still seems like there should be a better way...

Comment: Do let me know if you find an even better solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This will surely fail in following case 
2.2.2 :059 > Time.now.in_time_zone("Indiana (East)").strftime('%Z')
=> "EDT" 
2.2.2 :060 > Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").strftime('%Z')
=> "EDT"

Comment: Indiana (East) is on Eastern Time so the abbreviation would correctly be EST or EDT depending on the date.

Comment: This was really helpful to get the `EST` or `EDT` to match an expectation! in Rspec, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I looked all over for this answer, and I finally found what I was looking for.  I'm leaving the answer here so others might not have to look nearly as long and hard as I had to.

If you have access to ActiveSupport and dealing with TimeZone objects like this:

```
timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all[44]
```

then you can get to the abbreviation this way:

```
timezone.tzinfo.current_period.abbreviation
```

Comment: the zone info is in tzinfo, however this is basically a longer way of simply doing what ifightcrime mentioned above...for instance, User.take.created_at.zone

Comment: You can also use `strftime` to get the abbreviation directly from the `TZInfo::TimezoneProxy` instance.

Answer (score 8):

```
Time.now.zone
# => "UTC"
```

To use the default Timezone (if set) you can use:

```
Time.zone.now.zone
# => "CDT"
```

More info on that: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone-3D

Comment: This will also fail in following case
Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").zone
 => "EDT" 
2.2.2 :065 > Time.now.in_time_zone("Indiana (East)").zone
 => "EDT" 
Its tricky for day light saving and for zones that have same timings forexample above mentioned both zones are GMT -5. So ruby is confused.

Comment: If you want something other than the current TimeZone, you can use the following to supply your own: `Time.now.in_time_zone( "(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)" ).zone #=> "PDT"`

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you let your users choose their own timezone, you can render the timezone abbreviation as part of the datetime format. Try something like this in you appliction_helper.rb, then use it in a view to format a datetime object:

```
def format_datetime(datetime)
  datetime.strftime "%-d %b %Y, %H:%M %Z"
end
```

**Update**

If you're doing geolocation based on the users IP address, then you can do a timezone lookup based on that location. This question has actually been asked before but with regard to the latitude/longitude rather than the name of the timezone given.

Have a read of this one: [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude)

Comment: I'm pulling in the timezone via their ip + geolocation detection so I'm resolving it from the longer name.

Comment: Actually my question is a bit more specific.  I have geolocation working just fine.  The problem so far is that the result is the longer version of the timezone.  I'm looking to get EST(EDT), PST(PDT), UTC, IST, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [tzinfo](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo) gem, here's a way to obtain a mapping of time zone identifiers and their abbreviation:

```rb
TZInfo::TimezoneProxy.all.each_with_object({}) {|tz, obj|
  obj[tz.identifier] = tz.strftime("%Z")
}
```

The result hash contains 594 elements:

```rb
{"Africa/Abidjan"=>"GMT", "Africa/Accra"=>"GMT", "Africa/Addis_Ababa"=>"EAT", "Africa/Algiers"=>"CET", "Africa/Asmara"=>"EAT", "Africa/Asmera"=>"EAT", "Africa/Bamako"=>"GMT", "Africa/Bangui"=>"WAT", "Africa/Banjul"=>"GMT", "Africa/Bissau"=>"GMT", "Africa/Blantyre"=>"CAT", "Africa/Brazzaville"=>"WAT", "Africa/Bujumbura"=>"CAT", "Africa/Cairo"=>"EET", "Africa/Casablanca"=>"+01", "Africa/Ceuta"=>"CET", "Africa/Conakry"=>"GMT", "Africa/Dakar"=>"GMT", "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam"=>"EAT", "Africa/Djibouti"=>"EAT", "Africa/Douala"=>"WAT", "Africa/El_Aaiun"=>"+01", "Africa/Freetown"=>"GMT", "Africa/Gaborone"=>"CAT", "Africa/Harare"=>"CAT", "Africa/Johannesburg"=>"SAST", "Africa/Juba"=>"EAT", "Africa/Kampala"=>"EAT", "Africa/Khartoum"=>"CAT", "Africa/Kigali"=>"CAT", "Africa/Kinshasa"=>"WAT", "Africa/Lagos"=>"WAT", "Africa/Libreville"=>"WAT", "Africa/Lome"=>"GMT", "Africa/Luanda"=>"WAT", "Africa/Lubumbashi"=>"CAT", "Africa/Lusaka"=>"CAT", "Africa/Malabo"=>"WAT", "Africa/Maputo"=>"CAT", "Africa/Maseru"=>"SAST", "Africa/Mbabane"=>"SAST", "Africa/Mogadishu"=>"EAT", "Africa/Monrovia"=>"GMT", "Africa/Nairobi"=>"EAT", "Africa/Ndjamena"=>"WAT", "Africa/Niamey"=>"WAT", "Africa/Nouakchott"=>"GMT", "Africa/Ouagadougou"=>"GMT", "Africa/Porto-Novo"=>"WAT", "Africa/Sao_Tome"=>"GMT", "Africa/Timbuktu"=>"GMT", "Africa/Tripoli"=>"EET", "Africa/Tunis"=>"CET", "Africa/Windhoek"=>"CAT", "America/Adak"=>"HST", "America/Anchorage"=>"AKST", "America/Anguilla"=>"AST", "America/Antigua"=>"AST", "America/Araguaina"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Catamarca"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Cordoba"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Jujuy"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/La_Rioja"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Mendoza"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Salta"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/San_Juan"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/San_Luis"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Tucuman"=>"-03", "America/Argentina/Ushuaia"=>"-03", "America/Aruba"=>"AST", "America/Asuncion"=>"-03", "America/Atikokan"=>"EST", "America/Atka"=>"HST", "America/Bahia"=>"-03", "America/Bahia_Banderas"=>"CST", "America/Barbados"=>"AST", "America/Belem"=>"-03", "America/Belize"=>"CST", "America/Blanc-Sablon"=>"AST", "America/Boa_Vista"=>"-04", "America/Bogota"=>"-05", "America/Boise"=>"MST", "America/Buenos_Aires"=>"-03", "America/Cambridge_Bay"=>"MST", "America/Campo_Grande"=>"-04", "America/Cancun"=>"EST", "America/Caracas"=>"-04", "America/Catamarca"=>"-03", "America/Cayenne"=>"-03", "America/Cayman"=>"EST", "America/Chicago"=>"CST", "America/Chihuahua"=>"MST", "America/Coral_Harbour"=>"EST", "America/Cordoba"=>"-03", "America/Costa_Rica"=>"CST", "America/Creston"=>"MST", "America/Cuiaba"=>"-04", "America/Curacao"=>"AST", "America/Danmarkshavn"=>"GMT", "America/Dawson"=>"MST", "America/Dawson_Creek"=>"MST", "America/Denver"=>"MST", "America/Detroit"=>"EST", "America/Dominica"=>"AST", "America/Edmonton"=>"MST", "America/Eirunepe"=>"-05", "America/El_Salvador"=>"CST", "America/Ensenada"=>"PST", "America/Fort_Nelson"=>"MST", "America/Fort_Wayne"=>"EST", "America/Fortaleza"=>"-03", "America/Glace_Bay"=>"AST", "America/Godthab"=>"-03", "America/Goose_Bay"=>"AST", "America/Grand_Turk"=>"EST", "America/Grenada"=>"AST", "America/Guadeloupe"=>"AST", "America/Guatemala"=>"CST", "America/Guayaquil"=>"-05", "America/Guyana"=>"-04", "America/Halifax"=>"AST", "America/Havana"=>"CST", "America/Hermosillo"=>"MST", "America/Indiana/Indianapolis"=>"EST", "America/Indiana/Knox"=>"CST", "America/Indiana/Marengo"=>"EST", "America/Indiana/Petersburg"=>"EST", "America/Indiana/Tell_City"=>"CST", "America/Indiana/Vevay"=>"EST", "America/Indiana/Vincennes"=>"EST", "America/Indiana/Winamac"=>"EST", "America/Indianapolis"=>"EST", "America/Inuvik"=>"MST", "America/Iqaluit"=>"EST", "America/Jamaica"=>"EST", "America/Jujuy"=>"-03", "America/Juneau"=>"AKST", "America/Kentucky/Louisville"=>"EST", "America/Kentucky/Monticello"=>"EST", "America/Knox_IN"=>"CST", "America/Kralendijk"=>"AST", "America/La_Paz"=>"-04", "America/Lima"=>"-05", "America/Los_Angeles"=>"PST", "America/Louisville"=>"EST", "America/Lower_Princes"=>"AST", "America/Maceio"=>"-03", "America/Managua"=>"CST", "America/Manaus"=>"-04", "America/Marigot"=>"AST", "America/Martinique"=>"AST", "America/Matamoros"=>"CST", "America/Mazatlan"=>"MST", "America/Mendoza"=>"-03", "America/Menominee"=>"CST", "America/Merida"=>"CST", "America/Metlakatla"=>"AKST", "America/Mexico_City"=>"CST", "America/Miquelon"=>"-03", "America/Moncton"=>"AST", "America/Monterrey"=>"CST", "America/Montevideo"=>"-03", "America/Montreal"=>"EST", "America/Montserrat"=>"AST", "America/Nassau"=>"EST", "America/New_York"=>"EST", "America/Nipigon"=>"EST", "America/Nome"=>"AKST", "America/Noronha"=>"-02", "America/North_Dakota/Beulah"=>"CST", "America/North_Dakota/Center"=>"CST", "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem"=>"CST", "America/Nuuk"=>"-03", "America/Ojinaga"=>"MST", "America/Panama"=>"EST", "America/Pangnirtung"=>"EST", "America/Paramaribo"=>"-03", "America/Phoenix"=>"MST", "America/Port-au-Prince"=>"EST", "America/Port_of_Spain"=>"AST", "America/Porto_Acre"=>"-05", "America/Porto_Velho"=>"-04", "America/Puerto_Rico"=>"AST", "America/Punta_Arenas"=>"-03", "America/Rainy_River"=>"CST", "America/Rankin_Inlet"=>"CST", "America/Recife"=>"-03", "America/Regina"=>"CST", "America/Resolute"=>"CST", "America/Rio_Branco"=>"-05", "America/Rosario"=>"-03", "America/Santa_Isabel"=>"PST", "America/Santarem"=>"-03", "America/Santiago"=>"-03", "America/Santo_Domingo"=>"AST", "America/Sao_Paulo"=>"-03", "America/Scoresbysund"=>"-01", "America/Shiprock"=>"MST", "America/Sitka"=>"AKST", "America/St_Barthelemy"=>"AST", "America/St_Johns"=>"NST", "America/St_Kitts"=>"AST", "America/St_Lucia"=>"AST", "America/St_Thomas"=>"AST", "America/St_Vincent"=>"AST", "America/Swift_Current"=>"CST", "America/Tegucigalpa"=>"CST", "America/Thule"=>"AST", "America/Thunder_Bay"=>"EST", "America/Tijuana"=>"PST", "America/Toronto"=>"EST", "America/Tortola"=>"AST", "America/Vancouver"=>"PST", "America/Virgin"=>"AST", "America/Whitehorse"=>"MST", "America/Winnipeg"=>"CST", "America/Yakutat"=>"AKST", "America/Yellowknife"=>"MST", "Antarctica/Casey"=>"+11", "Antarctica/Davis"=>"+07", "Antarctica/DumontDUrville"=>"+10", "Antarctica/Macquarie"=>"AEDT", "Antarctica/Mawson"=>"+05", "Antarctica/McMurdo"=>"NZDT", "Antarctica/Palmer"=>"-03", "Antarctica/Rothera"=>"-03", "Antarctica/South_Pole"=>"NZDT", "Antarctica/Syowa"=>"+03", "Antarctica/Troll"=>"+00", "Antarctica/Vostok"=>"+06", "Arctic/Longyearbyen"=>"CET", "Asia/Aden"=>"+03", "Asia/Almaty"=>"+06", "Asia/Amman"=>"EET", "Asia/Anadyr"=>"+12", "Asia/Aqtau"=>"+05", "Asia/Aqtobe"=>"+05", "Asia/Ashgabat"=>"+05", "Asia/Ashkhabad"=>"+05", "Asia/Atyrau"=>"+05", "Asia/Baghdad"=>"+03", "Asia/Bahrain"=>"+03", "Asia/Baku"=>"+04", "Asia/Bangkok"=>"+07", "Asia/Barnaul"=>"+07", "Asia/Beirut"=>"EET", "Asia/Bishkek"=>"+06", "Asia/Brunei"=>"+08", "Asia/Calcutta"=>"IST", "Asia/Chita"=>"+09", "Asia/Choibalsan"=>"+08", "Asia/Chongqing"=>"CST", "Asia/Chungking"=>"CST", "Asia/Colombo"=>"+0530", "Asia/Dacca"=>"+06", "Asia/Damascus"=>"EET", "Asia/Dhaka"=>"+06", "Asia/Dili"=>"+09", "Asia/Dubai"=>"+04", "Asia/Dushanbe"=>"+05", "Asia/Famagusta"=>"EET", "Asia/Gaza"=>"EET", "Asia/Harbin"=>"CST", "Asia/Hebron"=>"EET", "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"=>"+07", "Asia/Hong_Kong"=>"HKT", "Asia/Hovd"=>"+07", "Asia/Irkutsk"=>"+08", "Asia/Istanbul"=>"+03", "Asia/Jakarta"=>"WIB", "Asia/Jayapura"=>"WIT", "Asia/Jerusalem"=>"IST", "Asia/Kabul"=>"+0430", "Asia/Kamchatka"=>"+12", "Asia/Karachi"=>"PKT", "Asia/Kashgar"=>"+06", "Asia/Kathmandu"=>"+0545", "Asia/Katmandu"=>"+0545", "Asia/Khandyga"=>"+09", "Asia/Kolkata"=>"IST", "Asia/Krasnoyarsk"=>"+07", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"=>"+08", "Asia/Kuching"=>"+08", "Asia/Kuwait"=>"+03", "Asia/Macao"=>"CST", "Asia/Macau"=>"CST", "Asia/Magadan"=>"+11", "Asia/Makassar"=>"WITA", "Asia/Manila"=>"PST", "Asia/Muscat"=>"+04", "Asia/Nicosia"=>"EET", "Asia/Novokuznetsk"=>"+07", "Asia/Novosibirsk"=>"+07", "Asia/Omsk"=>"+06", "Asia/Oral"=>"+05", "Asia/Phnom_Penh"=>"+07", "Asia/Pontianak"=>"WIB", "Asia/Pyongyang"=>"KST", "Asia/Qatar"=>"+03", "Asia/Qostanay"=>"+06", "Asia/Qyzylorda"=>"+05", "Asia/Rangoon"=>"+0630", "Asia/Riyadh"=>"+03", "Asia/Saigon"=>"+07", "Asia/Sakhalin"=>"+11", "Asia/Samarkand"=>"+05", "Asia/Seoul"=>"KST", "Asia/Shanghai"=>"CST", "Asia/Singapore"=>"+08", "Asia/Srednekolymsk"=>"+11", "Asia/Taipei"=>"CST", "Asia/Tashkent"=>"+05", "Asia/Tbilisi"=>"+04", "Asia/Tehran"=>"+0330", "Asia/Tel_Aviv"=>"IST", "Asia/Thimbu"=>"+06", "Asia/Thimphu"=>"+06", "Asia/Tokyo"=>"JST", "Asia/Tomsk"=>"+07", "Asia/Ujung_Pandang"=>"WITA", "Asia/Ulaanbaatar"=>"+08", "Asia/Ulan_Bator"=>"+08", "Asia/Urumqi"=>"+06", "Asia/Ust-Nera"=>"+10", "Asia/Vientiane"=>"+07", "Asia/Vladivostok"=>"+10", "Asia/Yakutsk"=>"+09", "Asia/Yangon"=>"+0630", "Asia/Yekaterinburg"=>"+05", "Asia/Yerevan"=>"+04", "Atlantic/Azores"=>"-01", "Atlantic/Bermuda"=>"AST", "Atlantic/Canary"=>"WET", "Atlantic/Cape_Verde"=>"-01", "Atlantic/Faeroe"=>"WET", "Atlantic/Faroe"=>"WET", "Atlantic/Jan_Mayen"=>"CET", "Atlantic/Madeira"=>"WET", "Atlantic/Reykjavik"=>"GMT", "Atlantic/South_Georgia"=>"-02", "Atlantic/St_Helena"=>"GMT", "Atlantic/Stanley"=>"-03", "Australia/ACT"=>"AEDT", "Australia/Adelaide"=>"ACDT", "Australia/Brisbane"=>"AEST", "Australia/Broken_Hill"=>"ACDT", "Australia/Canberra"=>"AEDT", "Australia/Currie"=>"AEDT", "Australia/Darwin"=>"ACST", "Australia/Eucla"=>"+0845", "Australia/Hobart"=>"AEDT", "Australia/LHI"=>"+11", "Australia/Lindeman"=>"AEST", "Australia/Lord_Howe"=>"+11", "Australia/Melbourne"=>"AEDT", "Australia/NSW"=>"AEDT", "Australia/North"=>"ACST", "Australia/Perth"=>"AWST", "Australia/Queensland"=>"AEST", "Australia/South"=>"ACDT", "Australia/Sydney"=>"AEDT", "Australia/Tasmania"=>"AEDT", "Australia/Victoria"=>"AEDT", "Australia/West"=>"AWST", "Australia/Yancowinna"=>"ACDT", "Brazil/Acre"=>"-05", "Brazil/DeNoronha"=>"-02", "Brazil/East"=>"-03", "Brazil/West"=>"-04", "CET"=>"CET", "CST6CDT"=>"CST", "Canada/Atlantic"=>"AST", "Canada/Central"=>"CST", "Canada/Eastern"=>"EST", "Canada/Mountain"=>"MST", "Canada/Newfoundland"=>"NST", "Canada/Pacific"=>"PST", "Canada/Saskatchewan"=>"CST", "Canada/Yukon"=>"MST", "Chile/Continental"=>"-03", "Chile/EasterIsland"=>"-05", "Cuba"=>"CST", "EET"=>"EET", "EST"=>"EST", "EST5EDT"=>"EST", "Egypt"=>"EET", "Eire"=>"GMT", "Etc/GMT"=>"GMT", "Etc/GMT+0"=>"GMT", "Etc/GMT+1"=>"-01", "Etc/GMT+10"=>"-10", "Etc/GMT+11"=>"-11", "Etc/GMT+12"=>"-12", "Etc/GMT+2"=>"-02", "Etc/GMT+3"=>"-03", "Etc/GMT+4"=>"-04", "Etc/GMT+5"=>"-05", "Etc/GMT+6"=>"-06", "Etc/GMT+7"=>"-07", "Etc/GMT+8"=>"-08", "Etc/GMT+9"=>"-09", "Etc/GMT-0"=>"GMT", "Etc/GMT-1"=>"+01", "Etc/GMT-10"=>"+10", "Etc/GMT-11"=>"+11", "Etc/GMT-12"=>"+12", "Etc/GMT-13"=>"+13", "Etc/GMT-14"=>"+14", "Etc/GMT-2"=>"+02", "Etc/GMT-3"=>"+03", "Etc/GMT-4"=>"+04", "Etc/GMT-5"=>"+05", "Etc/GMT-6"=>"+06", "Etc/GMT-7"=>"+07", "Etc/GMT-8"=>"+08", "Etc/GMT-9"=>"+09", "Etc/GMT0"=>"GMT", "Etc/Greenwich"=>"GMT", "Etc/UCT"=>"UTC", "Etc/UTC"=>"UTC", "Etc/Universal"=>"UTC", "Etc/Zulu"=>"UTC", "Europe/Amsterdam"=>"CET", "Europe/Andorra"=>"CET", "Europe/Astrakhan"=>"+04", "Europe/Athens"=>"EET", "Europe/Belfast"=>"GMT", "Europe/Belgrade"=>"CET", "Europe/Berlin"=>"CET", "Europe/Bratislava"=>"CET", "Europe/Brussels"=>"CET", "Europe/Bucharest"=>"EET", "Europe/Budapest"=>"CET", "Europe/Busingen"=>"CET", "Europe/Chisinau"=>"EET", "Europe/Copenhagen"=>"CET", "Europe/Dublin"=>"GMT", "Europe/Gibraltar"=>"CET", "Europe/Guernsey"=>"GMT", "Europe/Helsinki"=>"EET", "Europe/Isle_of_Man"=>"GMT", "Europe/Istanbul"=>"+03", "Europe/Jersey"=>"GMT", "Europe/Kaliningrad"=>"EET", "Europe/Kiev"=>"EET", "Europe/Kirov"=>"+03", "Europe/Lisbon"=>"WET", "Europe/Ljubljana"=>"CET", "Europe/London"=>"GMT", "Europe/Luxembourg"=>"CET", "Europe/Madrid"=>"CET", "Europe/Malta"=>"CET", "Europe/Mariehamn"=>"EET", "Europe/Minsk"=>"+03", "Europe/Monaco"=>"CET", "Europe/Moscow"=>"MSK", "Europe/Nicosia"=>"EET", "Europe/Oslo"=>"CET", "Europe/Paris"=>"CET", "Europe/Podgorica"=>"CET", "Europe/Prague"=>"CET", "Europe/Riga"=>"EET", "Europe/Rome"=>"CET", "Europe/Samara"=>"+04", "Europe/San_Marino"=>"CET", "Europe/Sarajevo"=>"CET", "Europe/Saratov"=>"+04", "Europe/Simferopol"=>"MSK", "Europe/Skopje"=>"CET", "Europe/Sofia"=>"EET", "Europe/Stockholm"=>"CET", "Europe/Tallinn"=>"EET", "Europe/Tirane"=>"CET", "Europe/Tiraspol"=>"EET", "Europe/Ulyanovsk"=>"+04", "Europe/Uzhgorod"=>"EET", "Europe/Vaduz"=>"CET", "Europe/Vatican"=>"CET", "Europe/Vienna"=>"CET", "Europe/Vilnius"=>"EET", "Europe/Volgograd"=>"+04", "Europe/Warsaw"=>"CET", "Europe/Zagreb"=>"CET", "Europe/Zaporozhye"=>"EET", "Europe/Zurich"=>"CET", "Factory"=>"-00", "GB"=>"GMT", "GB-Eire"=>"GMT", "GMT"=>"GMT", "GMT+0"=>"GMT", "GMT-0"=>"GMT", "GMT0"=>"GMT", "Greenwich"=>"GMT", "HST"=>"HST", "Hongkong"=>"HKT", "Iceland"=>"GMT", "Indian/Antananarivo"=>"EAT", "Indian/Chagos"=>"+06", "Indian/Christmas"=>"+07", "Indian/Cocos"=>"+0630", "Indian/Comoro"=>"EAT", "Indian/Kerguelen"=>"+05", "Indian/Mahe"=>"+04", "Indian/Maldives"=>"+05", "Indian/Mauritius"=>"+04", "Indian/Mayotte"=>"EAT", "Indian/Reunion"=>"+04", "Iran"=>"+0330", "Israel"=>"IST", "Jamaica"=>"EST", "Japan"=>"JST", "Kwajalein"=>"+12", "Libya"=>"EET", "MET"=>"MET", "MST"=>"MST", "MST7MDT"=>"MST", "Mexico/BajaNorte"=>"PST", "Mexico/BajaSur"=>"MST", "Mexico/General"=>"CST", "NZ"=>"NZDT", "NZ-CHAT"=>"+1345", "Navajo"=>"MST", "PRC"=>"CST", "PST8PDT"=>"PST", "Pacific/Apia"=>"+14", "Pacific/Auckland"=>"NZDT", "Pacific/Bougainville"=>"+11", "Pacific/Chatham"=>"+1345", "Pacific/Chuuk"=>"+10", "Pacific/Easter"=>"-05", "Pacific/Efate"=>"+11", "Pacific/Enderbury"=>"+13", "Pacific/Fakaofo"=>"+13", "Pacific/Fiji"=>"+12", "Pacific/Funafuti"=>"+12", "Pacific/Galapagos"=>"-06", "Pacific/Gambier"=>"-09", "Pacific/Guadalcanal"=>"+11", "Pacific/Guam"=>"ChST", "Pacific/Honolulu"=>"HST", "Pacific/Johnston"=>"HST", "Pacific/Kiritimati"=>"+14", "Pacific/Kosrae"=>"+11", "Pacific/Kwajalein"=>"+12", "Pacific/Majuro"=>"+12", "Pacific/Marquesas"=>"-0930", "Pacific/Midway"=>"SST", "Pacific/Nauru"=>"+12", "Pacific/Niue"=>"-11", "Pacific/Norfolk"=>"+12", "Pacific/Noumea"=>"+11", "Pacific/Pago_Pago"=>"SST", "Pacific/Palau"=>"+09", "Pacific/Pitcairn"=>"-08", "Pacific/Pohnpei"=>"+11", "Pacific/Ponape"=>"+11", "Pacific/Port_Moresby"=>"+10", "Pacific/Rarotonga"=>"-10", "Pacific/Saipan"=>"ChST", "Pacific/Samoa"=>"SST", "Pacific/Tahiti"=>"-10", "Pacific/Tarawa"=>"+12", "Pacific/Tongatapu"=>"+13", "Pacific/Truk"=>"+10", "Pacific/Wake"=>"+12", "Pacific/Wallis"=>"+12", "Pacific/Yap"=>"+10", "Poland"=>"CET", "Portugal"=>"WET", "ROC"=>"CST", "ROK"=>"KST", "Singapore"=>"+08", "Turkey"=>"+03", "UCT"=>"UTC", "US/Alaska"=>"AKST", "US/Aleutian"=>"HST", "US/Arizona"=>"MST", "US/Central"=>"CST", "US/East-Indiana"=>"EST", "US/Eastern"=>"EST", "US/Hawaii"=>"HST", "US/Indiana-Starke"=>"CST", "US/Michigan"=>"EST", "US/Mountain"=>"MST", "US/Pacific"=>"PST", "US/Samoa"=>"SST", "UTC"=>"UTC", "Universal"=>"UTC", "W-SU"=>"MSK", "WET"=>"WET", "Zulu"=>"UTC"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what works nicely for me (converts something like `"Australia/Sydney"` to it's acronym, e.g. `"AEDT"`)

```rb
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Australia/Sydney").tzinfo.current_period.abbreviation
=> "AEDT"
```

---

Here's a handy helper

```rb
def timezone_as_acronym(timezone_string)
  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(timezone_string).tzinfo.current_period.abbreviation
end

timezone_as_acronym("Australia/Sydney")
# => "AEDT"
```