# Display time with geographic location rather than plus/minus hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, ruby-on-rails-6

I included user time zones:

From [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5.2/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone-3D), adding this in `application_controller`

```
around_action :set_time_zone

private
  def set_time_zone
    if current_user
      Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone) { yield }
    else
      yield
    end
  end
```

which produces

```
2020-09-21 00:00:00 +1000
```

This is great, but it could be more user friendly to display something along the lines of

```
2020-09-21 00:00 Melbourne time
```

Note: the word 'time' in the above is a string, nothing dynamic
The word 'Melbourne' is from the options in the view created with `time_zone_options_for_select(f.object.time_zone, nil, ActiveSupport::TimeZone)` (from [here](https://blog.bullettrain.co/auto-detecting-a-users-time-zone-in-rails/))

#### Question

How do I adjust the `set_time_zone` method so that it displays `2020-09-21 00:00 Melbourne` or `2020-09-21 00:00 Melbourne time` rather than `2020-09-21 00:00:00 +1000`?

I have tried (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052441/5783745)):

```
  def set_time_zone
    if current_user
      Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone).strftime('%Z') { yield }
    else
      yield
    end
  end
```

but it returns the error: `no block given (yield)`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? To make debugging easier?

Comment: @ChristianBruckmayer purely for ux (I assume a lot of users would know a major city in their time zone but not everyone would know how many hours +/- GMT they are)

Comment: Presenting the time in the users TZ server side is a somewhat flawed idea as it will get in the way of caching. Instead use HTML5 time elements (with the time in UTC) and javascript to convert to the users local time on the client.