# Google Maps GMT timezone offset

Tags: maps

I have been going through the docs, but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I need to find the timezone offset of a clicked point on the map (e.g. GMT +2:00). All I need is the +2 part. Here's what I have so far:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});
    alert(event.latLng);
    alert(event.time_zone);
    var contentString = 'test';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString});  
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

});
```

Comment: Try this post - you cant do it with Google Maps alone... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude

Comment: Please remember that timezone offsets are not very safe to rely upon, as they are prone to change!!  (A lot of people forget about daylight savings time).