# How to get Standard timezone on the basis of latitude and longitude in java

Tags: java

I have latitude and longitude and want to find corresponding timezone.
such as for India

```
Latitude and Longitude - 21.7679° N, 78.8718° E  
In response GMT +5:30
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude

Comment: use a geocoding website API and just make reqests.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to achieve that.

First of all, I would recommend you to use an online service and not reinventing the wheel.

Apart from more classic service like Google and Yahoo through their APIs, you can also use some of the options listed here: [Timezone lookup from latitude longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can first use [GeoGoogle](http://geo-google.sourceforge.net/usage.html) java library to get the longitude/latitude from the city-state-country.

Next, you can use [EarthTools](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone) (and some java code of your own) mentioned by Lennart to get the timezone :)