# Get TimeZone using latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, timezone, latitude-longitude

In my Android app, I need to get **TimeZone** using latitude and longitude. I need to get `TimeZone` **without** using internet.

How could I achieve this? Is there any logic to get TimeZone using latitude and longitude?

Comment: it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude/41533#41533

Answer (score 0):

Since you state "without using the internet" the only option would be to have a local look-up table based on the lat/long with a resulting timezone "value". The table could be stored in a SQLlite table, populated with data that you obtain via webservices prior to loading onto the device.