# Get timezone of location offline

Tags: python, geolocation

I want to get the timezone of a location based on its coordinates without connecting to an external api.
is that possible in python?
I already tried to install pytzwhere without success.

Comment: In what way your use of pytzwhere wasn't successful? I think it's the way to perform timezone lookup based on coordinates using Python.

Comment: pytzwhere is a huge package, I was wondering if there is something lighter

Comment: Well, considering that coordinate->timezone mapping is everything but simple, I'm not at all surprised that pytzwhere is a huge package.

Comment: You may invent the wheel, and do your own parsing on the data in tz_world or tz_world_mp from http://efele.net/maps/tz/world/.

Comment: You may also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504/timezone-lookup-from-latitude-longitude or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tzwhere import tzwhere

print tzwhere.tzwhere().tzNameAt(38.897663,-77.036562)
```

America/New_York